# If $Z\mid W=w \sim Bern(w)$ and $W\sim Uniform(0,1)$, is it possible to obtain either $P(W\mid Z)$ or $P(Z)$ marginally?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that

$$
Z\mid W=w \sim Bern(w)
$$

and

$$
W\sim Uniform(0,1)
$$

That is, $Z$ is conditionally distributed as a Bernoulli random variable, with probability of success $w$, obtained from the Uniform distribution on the set $(0,1)$. I am wondering how I can derive the correct formula for the joint distribution $P(Z=z, W=w)$.

I have:

$$
P(Z, W) = P(Z\mid W) P(W)
$$

so that,

$$
P(Z=z, W=w) = w^z(1-w)^z \cdot \mathbb{1}(0 < w < 1)
$$

Now, I would like to find $P(Z)$ or $P(W=w\mid Z=z)$. However, these all seem to go against the relationship above. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ is a special case of the Beta distribution, which is the conjugate prior for the probability of a Bernoulli random variable:
$$ X \sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$$
$$ Z|X \sim Bernoulli (X)$$
then
$$X|Z \sim Beta\left( \alpha +Z, \beta+1 - Z\right).$$
Also the marginal density has a closed form expression, but it does noy have a name (to the best of my knowledge).

Now use the fact that if $W\sim U(0,1)$, then $W\sim Beta(1,1)$ and you get:
$$W|Z \sim Beta(1+Z, 2-Z).$$

As for the marginal distribution of $Z$, we have that
$$p(z) = \int_0^1 w^z (1-w)^{1-z} \mathrm d w.$$
This is the definition of the [Beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function); hence,
$$p(z) = B(1+z, 2-z);$$
where
$$B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\mathrm d t.$$

Comment: Thanks! For the marginal of $Z$, is it defined? Is it perhaps what we would get by doing: $P(Z) = \sum_w P(Z, W=w)$? In other words, is it the sum over the equation I have above where $P(Z=z, W=w) = w^z(1-w)^z \cdot \mathbb{1}(0 < w < 1)$?

Comment: Yes correct, if your summation over $W$ is interpreted as an integral.